# How do I classify using SVM Classifier?

Tags: svm, classification

I'm doing a project in liver tumor classification. Actually I initially used Region Growing method for liver segmentation and from that I segmented tumor using FCM.
I,then, obtained the texture features using Gray Level Co-occurence Matrix. My output for that was

stats =

```
autoc: [1.857855266614132e+000 1.857955341199538e+000]
contr: [5.103143332457753e-002 5.030548650257343e-002]
corrm: [9.512661919561399e-001 9.519459060378332e-001]
corrp: [9.512661919561385e-001 9.519459060378338e-001]
cprom: [7.885631654779597e+001 7.905268525471267e+001]
```

Now how should I give this as an input to the SVM program.

```
function [itr] = multisvm( T,C,tst )
%MULTISVM(2.0) classifies the class of given training vector according to the 
% given group and gives us result that which class it belongs.
% We have also to input the testing matrix

%Inputs: T=Training Matrix, C=Group, tst=Testing matrix
%Outputs: itr=Resultant class(Group,USE ROW VECTOR MATRIX) to which tst set belongs 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
% IMPORTANT: DON'T USE THIS PROGRAM FOR CLASS LESS THAN 3,             %
%            OTHERWISE USE svmtrain,svmclassify DIRECTLY or            %
%            add an else condition also for that case in this program. %
%            Modify required data to use Kernel Functions and Plot also%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                       Date:11-08-2011(DD-MM-YYYY)                    %
% This function for multiclass Support Vector Machine is written by
% ANAND MISHRA (Machine Vision Lab. CEERI, Pilani, India) 
% and this is free to use. email: anand.mishra2k88@gmail.com

% Updated version 2.0 Date:14-10-2011(DD-MM-YYYY)

u=unique(C);
N=length(u);
c4=[];
c3=[];
j=1;
k=1;
if(N>2)
    itr=1;
    classes=0;
    cond=max(C)-min(C);
    while((classes~=1)&&(itr<=length(u))&& size(C,2)>1 && cond>0)
%This while loop is the multiclass SVM Trick
        c1=(C==u(itr));
        newClass=c1;
        svmStruct = svmtrain(T,newClass);
        classes = svmclassify(svmStruct,tst);

% This is the loop for Reduction of Training Set
        for i=1:size(newClass,2)
            if newClass(1,i)==0;
                c3(k,:)=T(i,:);
                k=k+1;
            end
        end
        T=c3;
        c3=[];
        k=1;

% This is the loop for reduction of group
        for i=1:size(newClass,2)
            if newClass(1,i)==0;
                c4(1,j)=C(1,i);
                j=j+1;
            end
        end
        C=c4;
        c4=[];
        j=1;

        cond=max(C)-min(C); % Condition for avoiding group 
                            %to contain similar type of values 
                            %and the reduce them to process

% This condition can select the particular value of iteration
% base on classes
        if classes~=1
            itr=itr+1;
        end    
    end
end

end
```

Kindly guide me.

Images:
[image: tumor1]
[image: tumor2]
[image: tumor3]

Answer (score 0):

You have to take all the feature values you get and concatenate them into a feature vector.  Then for the SVM the features should be normalized so that the values in each dimension vary between -1 and 1, if I remember correctly.  I think libsvm has a function for doing the normalization.

So assuming your feature vector ends up having N dimensions, and you have M training instances, your training set should be an M x N matrix.  Then if you have P test instances, your test set should be a P x N matrix.

Comment: Thank you. But how to concatenate all the feature values into a feature vector?

Comment: @Gomathi: v = [stats.autoc, stats.contr, ...];

Comment: I got the feature vector. But I have some trouble with the normalistion. I tried out like this. v=[stats.contr,stats.corrm,stats.energ,stats.entro,stats.homom]
m=mean(v)
sd=std(v)
st=(v-m)/sd

Comment: You cannot normalize a single vector.  You need to put all your vectors into a matrix.  Then find the maximum and the minimum value in each column, and rescale the values in each column so that the minimum corresponds to -1 and the maximum corresponds to 1. Check out the Statistics Toolbox in Matlab, if you have access to it. It might also have functions that will help you.

Comment: Actually the feature vector 'v' is the output obtained for one image. Does 'You need to put all your vectors into a matrix' mean, for a few more images?

Comment: @Gomathi, not just a few more images, but your entire training set.  You cannot normalize a single vector.

Answer (score 0):

May I also suggest you a very popular implementation of SVM, called SVMLight http://svmlight.joachims.org/.

You can find examples on the website on how to use it. Mex-matlav wrapper for it is also available.

As pointed out by Dima, you need to concatenate the features?

btw can you tell me which dataset are you using for liver-tumor-classification?
Is it publicly available for download?